# ckanr function ds_search_sql or alternative

Tags: r, api, ckan, httr, jsonlite

What is the correct syntax for querying a REST API using ckanr and the ds_search_sql function?

An attempt at a reproducible  example, but maybe this isn't setup right to work.
e.g.  to query: http://data.surrey.ca/dataset/fraser-health-restaurant-inspection-reports/resource/30b38b66-649f-4507-a632-d5f6f5fe87f1 with a where clause.

```
library(ckanr)
url_base <- 'http://data.surrey.ca/api/action/datastore_search?sql='

query <- 'SELECT "*" from "30b38b66-649f-4507-a632-d5f6f5fe87f1" WHERE "InspType" = 'Follow-up'\''

results <- ds_search_sql(query_co2,url = url_base,as = "table")$records
```

or would it be easier to just use:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

url <- paste0("http://data.surrey.ca/api/action/",
                  "datastore_search_sql?",
                  "sql=",
                  URLencode("SELECT * from \"30b38b66-649f-4507-a632-d5f6f5fe87f19\"

                            WHERE \"InspType\" = 'Follow-up'

                            "))

returned  <- fromJSON(url)
df <- returned$result$records
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`ckanr` maintainer here. I tried the SQL statement, needed some fixing, but couldn't get it to work. Even though `InspType` column is definitely there, it kept saying `insptype column does not exist` - somehow it was getting lowercased, as far as I can tell not on the R side.

I'd suggest just pulling the whole thing down, then filtering with dplyr/data.table, eg.,

```
library(ckanr)
library(dplyr)
url_base <- 'http://data.surrey.ca'
ckanr_setup(url = url_base)
query <- 'SELECT * from "30b38b66-649f-4507-a632-d5f6f5fe87f1"'
x <- ds_search_sql(query, url = url_base, as = "table")$records
filter(tbl_df(x), InspType == "Follow-Up")
```

Comment: What was the fix that you made, but didn't work? What would have be right way to end the SQL line including the where clause if the column had been found?
`query <- 'SELECT "*" from "30b38b66-649f-4507-a632-d5f6f5fe87f1" WHERE "InspType = 'Follow-up'\'`

Comment: a number of changes, see the error messages from the ckan server if you try various iterations

Comment: What would the cause of this error be:
`Error in ds_search_sql(query, url = url_base, as = "table") : 
  "Bad request - Action name not known: datastore_search_sql"`

Comment: don't know - have not seen that error before. open an issue at https://github.com/ropensci/ckanr/issues/

Answer (score 0):

I just spent far too long trying to figure out how to run an SQL query via CKAN so a note for my future self...

My base query is: [https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c"](https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20from%20%22c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c%22)

The results are truncated at 32000 records ([as per the CKAN documentation](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/datastore.html#ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_search_sql)). The dataset includes records from as far back as 2003 so I wanted to filter by Year:

[https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c" WHERE Year > 2014](https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20from%20%22c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c%22%20WHERE%20Year%20%3E%202014)

This produces the error: `column \"year\" does not exist`

As noted by @sckott the table name has been lower-cased. So let's quote it:

[https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c" WHERE "Year" > 2014](https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20from%20%22c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c%22%20WHERE%20%22Year%22%20%3E%202014)

This produces the error: `operator does not exist: text > integer`

Can we `CAST()` the column to integer?

[https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c" WHERE CAST("Year" as integer) > 2014](https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20from%20%22c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c%22%20WHERE%20CAST(%22Year%22%20as%20integer)%20%3E%202014)

`Access denied: {'permissions': ['Not authorized to call function CAST']}`

How about...

[https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c" WHERE "Year"::integer > 2014](https://data.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20from%20%22c308bb0a-98a9-4cbb-bd0b-206d338ca06c%22%20WHERE%20%22Year%22::integer%20%3E%202014)

Eureka!

After all that, this advice still holds:

> I'd suggest just pulling the whole thing down, then filtering with
> dplyr/data.table

Comment: i have been trying to run the ckan api with a sql query no success, even the base query is not working. Here is the api  https://data.tn.gov/api/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "39ea268b-d62e-4f33-a3a2-3d4f9bad82ce". do we need to configure anything else in CKAN to have the sql queries work with ckan api's?